# How to provide one heading for complete page when using "Split-view" page in onsen ui

Tags: split, navigation, title, onsen-ui

I am working in Onsen Ui split view page functionality. I am creating a page from this  [link](https://onsen.io/reference/ons-split-view.html). My requirement is provide top title for complete page.

Comment: Provide at least an attempt.

Comment: @AndiPavllo Even though it's better if people try to do something before asking, that isn't a reason not to answer them. They will learn better if they try to do it themselves, but maybe sometimes they're unable to do it.

Comment: @IliaYatchev It's not a matter of answering or not. Stackoverflow's has not been made to just answer questions but also to help the users to grow up. The solution of the problem could have been easily discovered from the same documentation the user linked. An attempt would demonstrate that the user really tried to solve the issue instead of being [spoon-fed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spoon-feed).

Comment: @AndiPavllo I am new for understandng Onsen UI thats why i ask a question related with Split View functionality. I try many times for display single title for the above condition and at last i am able to do same before correct answer provided by IliaYatchev. But some times we need solution as fast as possible thats why i ask question in community. There is no thinking of Spoon Feed for any user who are asking question here. Because in some conditions same user is master in any other topic as well.

Comment: @donald I didn't mean that it was your specific case, I meant that's what happens usually when people ask for a solution without adding an attempt. My request was aimed to help you to find the solution with your own thinking, which would be more satisfying than just proving you a solution. Anyway, I'm glad Ilia's code helped you to solve your issue, enjoy your development with Onsen UI! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since each page in Onsen UI can have a toolbar - if you want to have a common title then you can just put the `ons-split-view` inside a page with a title.

```
<ons-page>
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Complete page title</div>
  </ons-toolbar>
  <ons-split-view var="mySplitView" secondary-page="menu.html" main-page="page1.html" main-page-width="70%" collapse="width 500px">
  </ons-split-view>
</ons-page>
```

Here's a [demo](http://codepen.io/IliaSky/pen/redVVM?editors=1000).